# what would be technology use to develope a job hunting website

Tags: struts, struts-1

which technology to use for making a job hunting site
struts1,struts2,spring or simple servlet,jsp
which one runs faster as using a framework might slow you down.

struts1-> abstract class based -> so they should be faster than struts2 which are based on interfaces. (Anybody tested that if not how to test it.)

and about the spring i had no idea... it is said to be lightweight but what that terms actually means technically.
faster bean resolution or lesse libraries in which terms ...that "term lightweight" holds.

Answer (score 1):

Use the one you are most familiar with. The technologies you mentioned are very generic/low-level, and not specific to a certain application such as a "job hunting website". The only slow-down you should worry about at this point is programmer productivity. If there really comes the time to do performance tuning later, this has probably nothing to do with how many bean classes and libraries need to be resolved, but with application (and database) design (on your end, not in the framework).

Comment: well... i repharse my question has anybody tested sturts1 vs struts2 in terms of request speed as the request passes through the stacktrace to got to the designate action compared to servlet jsp. and if not what can be used for testing purpouse for this specfic case.

Comment: Again, I doubt that any speed difference between struts1, struts2 and jsp will be significant compared to network latency, database access, executing business logic.